# SwiftUI View automatically scrolls to bottom without input

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to wrap my entire `View` (itself wrapped in a `VStack`) into a `ScrollView`. When I run the app in simulator (for various different devices) or physical device, as soon as the page loads, the view automatically scrolls to the bottom in two staggered movements (i.e. not smoothly). Of course, I want the user to see the top of the page first and be able to scroll down themselves.

I'm just using a basic `ScrollView { }` with no modifiers or inputs.

Is there something I need to add to the `ScrollView` to prevent this, or could this be caused by something else in my `View`?

EDIT 2: I found the answer (posted below), so I've edited my code down here so you can see what the problem was and how I fixed it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailViewTest: View {

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {

            VStack {

                [Content Removed for Clarity]

            } //End of main VStack

                .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
                .padding()

        } //End of Scroll View

    }
}
```

Comment: I would add more code so we can easily re-produce the error on our ends. That's the beauty of SwiftUI. We can easily re-produce if we have the majority of the code.

Comment: Thanks. I've added my code for the view I'm having problems with. I'm not sure how best to share code when I refer to other parts of my code (structs, classes, etc.) or local assets (images).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: I moved the .navigationBarTitle and .padding() outside of the ScrollView curly braces so they are modifying the ScrollView instead of the main VStack:

```
        ...

        } //End of main VStack

            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)

                } // End scroll view

            .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
            .padding()

    }
}
```

This must have just been a quirk with how SwiftUI is rendering the view and applying modifiers.

Note: I also added the .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity) to my VStack which I don't think was related to my problem, though you may find it helpful in making ScrollView behave properly.